# Can we give <td> width 100% if <tr> has many td's to be responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, html-table

I have a list of items to be listed in a table view i.e 4*4, 4 rows and with 4 coloums.
Each element in desktop view(1024+) has a fixed width (around 158px) and height (around 200px).
This site needs to be responsive, so i decided to display one td in each row in tablet view (768 and lesser) with NO Change in html and by adding the media queries and making td with 100%, it works. I want to make sure this is syntactically valid and browser compactable.

---

Here is the html structure

```
<tr>
    <td><div>........</div></td>
    <td><div>........</div></td>
    <td><div>........</div></td>
    <td><div>........</div></td>
</tr>
in desktop view each td will have a width of about 158px
```

---

```
<tr>
    <td><div>........</div></td>
    <td><div>........</div></td>
    <td><div>........</div></td>
    <td><div>........</div></td>
</tr>
in Tablet view view each td will have a width of 98% and 1% padding
```

Comment: This sounds fishy to me. Why not give each TD a 25% width all around?

Comment: TD width may be in % or px (25% or 158px) doesnt matter in desktop view.
My question is in tablet view(768px width) can i give each TD a width of 98%. is that syntactically valid ?

Comment: AFAIK, TD width, if expressed by %, should be as percent of the table. If the total sum of your TD width exceeds %100, you are doing it wrong. That said, it may work to give you the intended result - for this, you will have to test with all the browsers that you wish to support to see this result, but since it is not the intended use, I would do everything to avoid it.